# Is there a console command to change battlefield 3 mouse sensitivity?

Tags: battlefield-3, mouse

is there a command in battlefield 3 to change the mouse sensitivity with a numerical value in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit your config file for a more precise sensitivity adjustment.

Configs are located in:

```
My Documents/Battlefield 3/PROF_SAVE_profile
```

**Back this file up before making any changes.**

Open in Notepad and edit these values. I haven't tweaked these in the config since beta when there was a bug with the sensitivity slider, so I couldn't tell you what the scheme0/1/2 values affect.

```
GstInput.MouseSensitivity
GstInput.Scheme0Sensitivity
GstInput.Scheme1Sensitivity
GstInput.Scheme2Sensitivity
```

Edit: Try this in the console

```
GstInput.MouseSensitivity 0.418605
```

Edit the value to your preference.

Answer (score 0):

C:\Users\yourname\Documents\Battlefield 3\settings
the filename is PROF_SAVE_profile which can be opened with wordpad

the command that works is the second

```
GstInput.MouseRawInput 1
GstInput.MouseSensitivity 0.001347
GstInput.MouseSensitivityVehicle 0.020000
```